# Update ongoing notification stuck after reboot

Tags: google-play-store

I selected to upgrade all of my applications, but my phone shut down for some reason during the upgrade. After restarting, I noticed that the upgrade was stuck so I cancelled the updates. Unfortunately, I still saw a notification that the other app were being downloaded. Even after restarting more times, clearing market data and killing the download process, the issue remains. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strange that clearing the data did not fix it.  However, you should be able to click on each of the apps that are pretend-downloading and hit Cancel.

Comment: I had already actually tried that. I then restarted a few more times and turned my Internet connection on and off and it eventually disappeared. I have no clue what fixed it